# can i close my apple id account and open a new one?

Tags: apple-id

My apple id is associated with a .me account that i use for nothing else.  I would like to have an apple id associated with my most active email account (a work account, but i am self employed).  I see that a .me apple id cannot be changed but can it be closed and could i then open a new account with the better email address?  What would i lose?  Contacts?  Notes?  Old .me emails?  Apps purchased under the .me account?  The last two are not a problem, but the first two are...
THanks

Comment: Have you looked carefully into the option of changing your primary Apple ID email to one that you use? Go to [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/) and see if you can add an alternate email or change your primary, if that is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that contacts and notes can be synched to whatever Apple ID is set up, so changing accounts shouldn't affect these things. You will lose access to any Music, Movies, or Apps bought under the old Apple ID.